# Absolute difference with logical operators only

Tags: fpga, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to implement in a FPGA the test formula:

```
abs(a-b)>1
```

a and b are unsigned 3 bits (0 to 7).

The truth table is as follow:

[image]

The test is:

```
reg[2:0] a, b;
((a > b + 3'd1) || (b > a + 3'd1))
```

A "dumb" test without the "+1" operator would be:

```
[a==0 && b>=2] || [a==1 && b>=3] || [a==2 && (b==0 || b>=4)] || [a==3 && (b<=1 || b>=5)] || [a==4 && (b<=2 || b>=6)] || [a==5 && (b<=3 ||b==7)]
```

There is obviously symmetry. How could I implement with only logical gates (or with a few tests)? The objective is to have something the simplest possible (aka. taking the least area space) and I would like to avoid any 'complex' operator.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not use your first implementation and let the synthesis tools optimize it for you? They're actually very good at that, and there's no need to do weird things in the source code to get a minimal implementation.

Comment: The basic logic element in an FPGA is not a logic gate, it's a 32-bit (32x1) RAM. (Or sometimes 16-bit or 64-bit)

Comment: In an FPGA with 64-bit LUTs, this function would require only a single LUT.  With 32-bit LUTs, you'd need three, and with 16-bit LUTs, it would require five. Some FPGAs have additional hard resources (e.g., muxes) that could reduce these numbers.

Comment: @DaveTweed, can you please explain in more details? It's a Lattice MachXO3.

Comment: The basic logic element in your FPGA is a 4-input LUT, as shown in the [datasheet](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/DataSheets/MachXO23/DS1047-MachXO3-Family-Data-Sheet.pdf?document_id=50121) (figure 2-4 on page 2-4) -- and there are indeed additional muxes available (OFX0 and OFX1). Minimizing "gates" is not the goal; it's minimizing the number of LUTs. As I said, the synthesis tools are already very good at taking complex combinatorial functions like yours and mapping them efficiently into LUTs.

Comment: You tell the synthesis tool **what** you want, not **how** you think it should be done.  Then it goes and does an embarrassingly better job of it than you ever could.  It's the same thing with compiled software languages these days.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you write HDL code and let the tool sort out the logic.

This is just one of many ways to do this:

```
assign bigger_then_one = a > b ? ( (a-b) > 1) : ( (b-a) > 1 );
```

The example is in Verilog, I am sure there is a one liner for VHDL as well but that varies depending on the type you want to produce, e.g. std_logic or boolean or ....

---

Just to show what happens I made a top level module and ran it through Vivado:

```
module ee (
   input    [2:0] a,
   input    [2:0] b,
   output   bigger_then_one
   );

   assign bigger_then_one = a > b ? ( (a-b) > 1) : ( (b-a) > 1 );

endmodule
```

Result:
[image]

A single LUT comes out.